# Displaying all photos from a child table in Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am brand new to django and have run into a problem when trying to display a html page that contains multiple images.

What I am trying to achieve is for a parent record display all the related images, In my example below, ShowroomDetail is the parent and ShowroomPhoto is the child.

Using the Django admin screens, I have created one showroom and uploaded two images as children of this showroom. I can view both the showroom and images without an issue from the Django admin screens and can see that they are related.

Unfortunately when I try to display the same information using a template, I encounter the an error:

> 'ShowroomPhoto' object is not iterable

What am I doing wrong? In case of need I am using Django 1.6.2

Here are the contents of the various files.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class ShowroomDetail(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4000)     

class ShowroomPhoto(models.Model):
    showroom = models.ForeignKey(ShowroomDetail, related_name='photos')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from showroom.models import ShowroomDetail, ShowroomPhoto

# Create your views here.

def Displayshowroom(request):
   showroom = ShowroomDetail.objects.all()[0]
   photos = ShowroomPhoto.objects.all()[showroom.id]
   return render(request, 'showroom.html', {'showroom': showroom, 'photos': photos})
```

**showroom.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Showroom</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <ul>
            <li>{{ showroom.title }}</li>
            <li>{{ showroom.description }}</li>            
            <li>{{ showroom.id }}</li>          
            {% for photo in photos %}
               <li><img src="{{ photo.url }}" height="420"/></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </u
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `photos = ShowroomPhoto.objects.all()[showroom.id]` you are retrieving a single object, and not the queryset due to the `[]` (subscript).

You probably mean to `filter` instead:

Change

```
photos = ShowroomPhoto.objects.all()[showroom.id]
```

to

```
photos = ShowroomPhoto.objects.filter(showroom__id=showroom.id)
```

Also, in the templates:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
   <li><img src="{{ photo.url }}" height="420"/></li>
{% endfor %}
```

should be

```
{% for photo in photos %}
   <li><img src="{{ photo.photo.url }}" height="420"/></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, your code would work fine.

Comment: Perfect, I have been trying to work this out over the last two nights. Thank you for the very prompt response